# Adding the same existing field twice(more than once) within same content type

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-7, cck

I want to reuse the same existing field more than once within the same content type.

Assume that `ContentType1` has a field `Phone-Number`.

Now I want to use the `existing field Phone-Number` from ContentType1 within ContentType2, but three times. Assume that I want to have contact numbers of three people in the ContentType2. So I want to use the existing field `Phone-Number` thrice.

It doesn't allow, as once I add the existing field it doesn't appear next time. I tried to export and import. But that didn't work either

Comment: How about [field_reference](https://drupal.org/project/field_reference) - "Depending on configuration, authors can pick fields from the same node/entity, from other nodes/entities, from specific revisions, from specific languages, or even a specific delta value within the field. Fields can be displayed using either the 'full' or 'teaser' mode from their original node/entity."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A content type can only have a particular field added to it once - this is by design and cannot be changed without some serious hacking of the module. You can change the field's settings to allow for multiple values, I think this is as close as you're going to get though.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. But since you have confirmed that it can't happen, I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot add the same existing  field multiple time in same content type. You can Use the every existing field only once in every content type.